# Login Greeter takes 20~30 sec (after bootup apparently finished) to appear

Tags: login, lightdm, login-screen, gdm, sddm

I looked into [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056133/lightdm-or-x-server-start-very-slow-takes-a-couple-of-minutes) among a few others (on and off SO) for a solution.

The upvoted (but **not** accepted) answer to that question, suggests **entropy** might be a problem.
I have infact from the beginning both `haveng` and `rng-tools` installed and enabled, and the entropy is pretty high (as per the comments on that answer, which suggest something close to 4000 as a good value).

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
$ 3703
```

I disabled a bunch of services, like Docker, lxc, etc that I thought might have been slowing down the boot process. Here is the critical-chain output after that. I don't think, there are any unnecessary services being started.

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @18.632s
└─multi-user.target @18.632s
  └─ModemManager.service @12.750s +3.349s
    └─polkit.service @9.288s +3.409s
      └─basic.target @8.854s
        └─sockets.target @8.854s
          └─libvirtd-admin.socket @8.854s
            └─libvirtd.socket @8.848s +5ms
              └─sysinit.target @8.817s
                └─systemd-sysctl.service @8.795s +21ms
                  └─systemd-modules-load.service @2.849s +5.941s
                    └─systemd-journald.socket @2.737s
                      └─-.mount @2.733s
                        └─system.slice @2.733s
                          └─-.slice @2.733s
```

Here is my lightdm.log.

```
[+7.13s] DEBUG: Process 1994 exited with return value 0
[+7.13s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Exit status of /sbin/prime-offload: 0
[+7.13s] DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) (child_setup specified) 
[+7.13s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+7.13s] DEBUG: Session pid=1999: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'lightdm'
[+7.40s] DEBUG: Session pid=1999: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+7.40s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+7.40s] DEBUG: Session pid=1999: Running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter
[+7.40s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/lightdm
[+7.40s] DEBUG: Session pid=1999: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log
[+30.54s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+30.54s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c1
[+30.54s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c1
[+30.54s] DEBUG: Session c1 is already active
[+48.16s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.30.0 api=1 resettable=false
[+49.90s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for junaid
[+49.90s] DEBUG: Session pid=6578: Started with service 'lightdm', username 'junaid'
[+49.92s] DEBUG: Session pid=6578: Got 1 message(s) from
```

I already tried switching to amdgpu-pro drivers from the [amd website](https://www.amd.com/de/support/1876?language=zh-hant) and that changed nothing. I reverted to the open source drivers.

I have also switched from lightdm to sddm and to gdm3 alternatively. Here is the output for that.

- With lightdm

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 7.564s (kernel) + 18.663s (userspace) = 26.228s 
graphical.target reached after 18.632s in userspace
```

With lightdm, I just have a blank screen for ~30 seconds before the greeter appears.

- With sddm

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 6.667s (kernel) + 16.169s (userspace) = 22.837s 
graphical.target reached after 16.155s in userspace
```

Interesting thing about sddm is, the mouse cursor (although frozen) already appears almost immediately but the greeter does not appear for the next ~20 seconds.

- With gdm3

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 6.562s (kernel) + 52.061s (userspace) = 58.624s 
graphical.target reached after 52.047s in userspace
$ systemd-analyze blame
41.779s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                               
 5.738s systemd-modules-load.service                                             
 5.519s udisks2.service                                                          
 4.411s networkd-dispatcher.service                                              
 3.809s accounts-daemon.service                                                  
 3.443s tor@default.service                                                      
 3.011s qemu-kvm.service                                                         
 2.930s uml-utilities.service                                                    
 2.614s dev-sdb5.device                                                          
 2.459s ModemManager.service                                                     
 2.205s polkit.service                                                           
 2.158s avahi-daemon.service                                                     
 2.136s NetworkManager.service                                                   
 2.124s dundee.service                                                           
 2.005s ofono.service                                                            
 1.958s gpu-manager.service                                                      
 1.920s grub-common.service  
...
```

And finally Syslog shows that the kernel goes through with the bootup pretty fast (~4sec), till the following snags hit, taking up 20~30 seconds, which is about the time the screen remains blank&unresponsive before the login screen appears.

```
Dec 18 12:04:03 my-desktop NetworkManager[1057]: <info>  [1639825443.5387] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Dec 18 12:04:13 my-desktop systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Dec 18 12:04:22 my-desktop systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Succeeded.
Dec 18 12:04:22 my-desktop systemd-timesyncd[996]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Dec 18 12:04:26 my-desktop systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Dec 18 12:04:40 my-desktop systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 1000.
```

With gdm3, the boot-splash screen remains frozen for ~30 seconds before the login greeter appears.

I have a not so bad system put together a couple of years ago, with Ryzen 7 processor, 32GB RAM, 256GB SSD for the OS, and I am using an up to date Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

So if there is a solution to this problem, it has eluded me in the last 2~3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Ubuntu 20.04.3 in a Lenovo Thinkbook. The problem is related to the fingerprint reader login option which does not work properly.  I removed this option and it works perfectly.

You can verify it is running in a terminal with `journalctl -f`.  Then you lock the screen (in my case Windows key + L) and log again and see the results of the process. That will show the elements calling during the login process.

Comment: Hi @Cesar, thanks for the answer. Actually, I have a desktop PC (and not a laptop). But I tried it just now anyways. I did not see anything about a finger print reader. There was just one message about unlocking the gnome-keyring when I locked and then unlocked the screen.